# Blocking a service to countries with UFW

Tags: firewall, ubuntu-10.04, ufw

I am using UFW trying to block SSH access from multiple countries. I have been successful **completely** blocking access but I need a refinement:

The server needs to allow world access to other services (ex. WWW, RSYNC, FTP) but block SSH. Using the before.rules, I am able to block without a problem *all* access from an offending IP range, ex.

-A ufw-before-input -s xxx.xxx.0.0/16 -j DROP

Is there a way to use before.rules and modify the above statement to do this for just to block SSH? I can also create hundreds of rules using the command prompt but I prefer to use the before.rules setup because it is easier to manage.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these switches to the command:

`-p tcp --dport 22`

So:

`-A ufw-before-input -s xxx.xxx.0.0/16 -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP`